Which AppIcon sizes to use for visionOS app icon
If I use

front: 512
middle: 512
back: 1024

it build and run, but if I use

front: 512
middle: 512
back: 512

then got this error:

Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.solidimagestack The last visionOS App Icon Layer with content, "Back", must exactly fill the image stack. Its current frame is {{0, 0}, {256, 256}} while the visionOS App Icon's size is {512, 512}.

What is wrong? Why not all three need the same size?
When I go for option 1, that around log there are to many padding / space. Our back image is a plain white image.

If I put in 1024 for front as this says, that Xcode freeze:
https://uxplanet.org/apple-vision-pro-spatial-design-101-part-3-5a0bffc3e92
